# BLE device paring with android device and once the device come to range and after connecting to do we get any callBack or Broadcast?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a question:

I've one BLE Device its connected to phone and paired. When the device goes out of range and comes back in to range, will it connect again and trigger the callback after coming into range.

Comment: You won't get a "connection possible" event when the device returns to range, if this is your question. (To be honest, I am not completely sure what exactly you are asking.)

Comment: If you when you execute connectGatt, set the autoConnect parameter to true then you will get onConnectionState callback when the device disconnects and connects.